# MVC C#: Actualizar vista cuando se añade fila en SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc

Buenas, estoy desarrollando un proyecto basado en MVC que está configurado con una base de datos de SQL Server externa. En la base de datos se registran los eventos que se producen en un servidor de Asterisk, y en la vista principal se listan todas las entradas que hay en la tabla de eventos contenida en dicha BD.

Después de esta breve explicación, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de actualizar la vista automáticamente cuando hay un nuevo evento en la base de datos sin tener que "refrescar" la aplicación. He investigado para hacerlo con la librería SignalR, pero los ejemplos que he encontrado hacen la actualización a partir de los cambios que realiza un cliente y se lo "propaga al resto", no en función de añadir una nueva fila a la base de datos.

He mirado también si hay alguna forma de que sql server envíe una alerta cuando haya un cambio, pero sólo he encontrado cómo configurarlo con un correo electrónico.

Supongo que siempre está la opción de sondear la base de datos a ver si por ejemplo el número de filas ha aumentado, pero este método en principio lo descarto por lo ineficiente que es.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te recomiendo que vayas por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas cómo funciona el sitio. Revisa el siguiente material y cuando tengas un ejemplo funcionando, te agradecería que lo publiques para que más desarrolladores puedan avanzar sus proyectos: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/real-time-web-applications-with-signalr - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Broadcast-Real-time-SQL-69dd9fcc - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/883702/Real-Time-Notifications-using-SignalR-and-SQL-Depe

Comment: http://www.venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/ Éxitos y buena suerte :D Espero ver dentro de poco un ejemplo para el sitio :D

Comment: Muchas gracias por el material.

Comment: De nada hermano, dale con todo el power! Por cierto, ahora que sabes cómo funciona el sitio y tu pregunta sigue siendo la misma, ésta cae como demasiado amplia y potencialmente puede ser cerrada. Una vez que sigas con la investigación y hagas el intento, te ayudamos con mucho gusto a completar esa feature que necesitas. Saludos :D